# Getting error like 'busid' in field list is ambiguous

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to run the following sql query

```
"select case when a.position < b.position then busid else null end as busid from (select busid,position from route where routid=$start) a join (select busid,position from route where routid=$end) b on a.busid = b.busid"
```

But when I am trying to run the query then it is giving error :

```
Column 'busid' in field list is ambiguous
```

What may be the possible error ?

Comment: Use proper alias with fields. `a.busid` or `b.busid`.

Comment: can you plz elaborate ?

Comment: MySQL is confusing in selecting the column value because you may have same column in both the tables. so to round this issue use table aliases before column names as suggested by the sougata.